# How can I make the NeoTerm command start halfway down the screen?

Tags: neovim, plugin-neoterm

I have a bunch of macros that invoke the `:T <command>` functionality of Neovim's [neoterm](https://github.com/kassio/neoterm) plugin. But as you can see, it creates the terminal right near the top of the screen:

[image]

This forces me to use the mouse to move the bottom of the buffer down so I can see my code. Is there a way to instruct the `:T` command to start the buffer halfway down the screen, like this?

[image]

#### EDIT - Explanation of `:T` command

[NeoTerm](https://github.com/kassio/neoterm) is a wrapper around the `:terminal` command so that it does not open a new terminal each time (ie: uses the same terminal). It is invoked using `:T <command>` It also allows for terminals in a buffer on the same window that receive commands from the current buffer.

Comment: What exactly is the `:T` command? Can you check if this happens with `nvim --clean`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt apols I had forgotten about neoterm! I though it was native nvim. Question modified accordingly

Comment: please try if this also happens with the default `:term` command. If yes, try it out with `nvim --clean` if no, open an issue wit the NeoTerm plugin